# Regex alphanumeric and other special characters

Tags: regex

I'm looking for regex for alphanumeric and `# , . ( ) _ - / \ "` only allow.

Comment: did you try anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex is `[\d\w#,()."\/\\-]`

Check the regex at

http://regex101.com/r/tC2mU7

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try this.

Answer (score 0):

Suppossing you need at least one of this characters I think this might work

```
/[A-Za-z0-9#,\(\)_\-\/\\"]+/
```

Comment: replacing the + with a ? it works for "no characters" as well :D

Comment: You could also just test it quite fasrt with http://regexpal.com/ or http://rubular.com/ or ....

Comment: `_`–`/` is an invalid range.

Comment: You're right :D Edited to correct